# AWS Lambda + openssl

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, openssl, aws-lambda

I have an encrypted content stored in /tmp/encryptedConfig.txt
I want to execute

```
openssl smime -decrypt -binary -in /tmp/encryptedConfig.txt -inkey ./privatekey.pem
```

but it is throwing an error. (I am using exec command and privatekey is stored locally in lambda).
How can i send the encrypted file to this command?
Please help. Thank you

Comment: What is the error you are getting?

Comment: { Error: Command failed: openssl smime -decrypt -text -in /tmp/encryptedConfig.txt -inkey ./privatekey.pem
Error reading S/MIME message
139963213862752:error:0D0D40D1:asn1 encoding routines:SMIME_read_ASN1:no content type:asn_mime.c:451:

at ChildProcess.exithandler (child_process.js:275:12)

Comment: It is not clear to me what the root cause might be. However, I doubt this is a Lambda-specific problem. The way I'd start investigating it is by starting an EC2 instance from same AMI as Lambda (see https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/current-supported-versions.html), and try to replicate it manually. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

The format of the encrypted file being sent to lambda was incorrect and hence the error. I was sending it in JSON format. I sent it in string format using Out-String. It worked with the same commands without any error. Thank you :)